# I am Learning FastApi and i am facing this issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, fastapi

I'm trying to create a `product` API but I am facing this issue after sending a request to the API:

```py
new_product = models.products(name=requests.name, price=requests.price)
AttributeError: module 'fastapi.requests' has no attribute 'name'
```

This is my code:

#### main.py

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, requests
from typing import Optional
import schemas, models
from database import engine, SessionLocal
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.post('/product')
def create(product: schemas.Products, db : Session = Depends(get_db)):
    new_product = models.products(name=requests.name, price=requests.price)
    db.add(new_product)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_product)
    return new_product
```

#### models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from database import Base

class products(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'products'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String)
    price = Column(Integer)
```

#### database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQL_URL = 'sqlite:/// product.db'

engine = create_engine(SQL_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False})

SessionLocal = sessionmaker(bind=engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)

Base = declarative_base()
```

#### schemas.py

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Products(BaseModel):
    name: str
    price: int
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to get the data sent to the API endpoint, you should be using `product.name` and `product.price`, instead of `requests.XXX`.

You are importing `requests` from FastAPI (`from fastapi import ... requests`), and that is completely unrelated to your API!

Answer (score 1):

Like Jason say is better get info from schema but if you want all the request include the body, headers ... etc you need Request no requests

```
from fastapi import  Request
@app.post("/")
async def fast_service(request: Request):
    body =await request.body()

    return
```